# Daemon threads terminate in jvm

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

i read about Daemon threads in internet i found it's not terminate either we JVM terminate
Is it mean after we close our java program also Daemon threads can run?

"Daemon threads die when the Java VM exits" is it correct?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You may want to look at Internet resources/tutorials again. If you still have specific questions, come back and show us what you're referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daemon threads are Java threads, and as such, they will die when JVM exits, same as anything that runs in JVM. Java threads can only run when the JVM is up. So

> "Daemon threads die when the Java VM exits" is it correct?

Yes it is.

The difference between daemon threads and non-daemon threads is that the JVM will keep running as long as there are still non-daemon threads running. Once there are no more non-daemon threads running, the JVM exits, no matter how many daemon threads are still running.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's a daemon or not, a Java thread runs on a Java virtual machine. If the virtual machine dies, every Java thread running on it dies with it, including daemon threads. So yes, your last sentence is correct.

What makes a daemon thread special is that the JVM shuts down when there are only daemon threads running, just as if there weren't any threads running at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For me, daemon thread it's like house keeper for user threads.
If all user threads finished , the daemon thread has no job and 
killed by JVM.
I explained it in the [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/OQLRiZwnXUM).